# F# type constraints on enums

Tags: f#, enums

I'm trying to define a generic conversion operator from a string to an Enum, and I'd like to use it like this:

```
let day = asEnum<DayOfWeek>("Monday")
```

But with this implementation:

```
let asEnum<'a, 'b when 'a: (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and 'a :> ValueType and 'a : enum<'b>> text = 
    match Enum.TryParse<'a>(text)  with
    | true, value -> Some value
    | false, _ -> None
```

I can only use it like this:

```
    let day = asEnum<DayOfWeek,_>("Monday")
```

or this:

```
    let day:DayOfWeek option = asEnum("Monday")
```

If I omit the `'a : enum<'b>` altogether from the type constraint, I can have it as I want, but then if someone doesn't specify the type it will default to `int`, which I really don't like, I'd prefer it to give a compile time error like it does when I specify a constraint

Maybe there's any trick to just specify one type parameter and have the other one infered? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Unfortunately, in order to augment the constraint it seems you have to spell it all out:</strike> (as kvb pointed out, you can avoid duplicating the constraints on `TryParse` by adding the `'T : enum<int>` constraint outside the angle brackets)

This also works:

```
let asEnum<'T 
  when 'T : enum<int>
  and 'T : struct
  and 'T :> ValueType
  and 'T : (new : unit -> 'T)> text =
  match Enum.TryParse<'T>(text) with
  | true, value -> Some value
  | _ -> None
```

This gives a compile-time error if the underlying type isn't `int`:

```
type ByteEnum =
  | None = 0uy

asEnum<ByteEnum> "None" //ERROR: The type 'int' does not match the type 'byte'
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
let asEnum s :'a option when 'a:enum<'b> =
    match System.Enum.TryParse s with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | _ -> None

// works, but warns that type params shouldn't be given explicitly
asEnum<System.Reflection.BindingFlags,_> "DeclaredOnly"    
// also okay
(asEnum "DeclaredOnly" : System.Reflection.BindingFlags option)
```

Comment: Holy cow. I didn't even know that was valid syntax. I think if you change it to `'a:enum<int>` that will give him what he wants. He could also do `let e : System.Reflection.BindingFlags option = asEnum "DeclaredOnly"` to avoid the warning.

Comment: Why does this work, yet putting the same constraint between `<` `>` doesn't?

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think @ovastus wants `int` to be forced, he wants it to be inferred if possible (which it is).

Comment: That's much nicer on the implementation side, but at the usage side, it's actually worse, as in addition to not still having to specify the  _ extra type argument, it always give a warning :( I'm trying to optimize the usage, even if the definition of asEnum is very clunky. Still cool that you don't have to spit it all out when putting outside <>

Comment: @ovatsus: What usage are you hoping for?

Comment: @ovastus - I see now that I misread your question.  Now I'm not sure why you're unhappy with your original implementation - what's wrong with `asEnum<DayOfWeek,_> "Monday"`?  I don't think you can pretend that there are fewer type parameters than there really are, so I doubt you'll be able to improve on this without fixing the enum's underlying type (as Daniel has).

Comment: This: asEnum<System.Reflection.BindingFlags> "DeclaredOnly"
I just want users of the code to not have to put the clumsy _

Comment: It's weird to have to specify two type parameters when there's only only value being passed, but I guess it is they way it is

Comment: @ovatsus: Under most circumstances a well-placed type annotation removes the need for explicit type args so this isn't an issue, for example: `match asEnum "Black" with Some e -> e : ConsoleColor | None -> failwith "!"`

Answer (score 1):

A little update something like 3 years afterwards ^_^

Using this string extension to convert string to an enum

```
type System.String with
        /// Strongly-typed shortcut for Enum.TryParse(). 
        member this.ToEnum<'a when 'a :> System.Enum and 'a : struct and 'a : (new: unit -> 'a)> () =
            let ok, v = System.Enum.TryParse<'a>(this, true)
            if ok then Some v else None
```

Be careful with your enum declaration.

```
type failingEnum =
            | FirstValue
            | SecondValue
            | AnotherValue

type compliantEnum =
            | FirstValue = 0
            | SecondValue = 1
            | AnotherValue = 2
```

Then

```
let x = "whatever".ToEnum<failingEnum>(); 
//- will give error failingEnum is not compatible with the type System.Enum

let x = "whatever".ToEnum<compliantEnum>(); 
//- will succeed !
```

Comment: Technically, `failingEnum` is a union type and not an enum. That's why it fails.

Comment: Sure ... Thanks for your comment. That's why I added the comment on it, cause one often define enum as union. I was part of those not so long ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I tried was this:

```
type AsEnum = 

    static member Get<'a, 'b when 'a: (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and 'a :> ValueType and 'a : enum<int>> (text:string) =

        match Enum.TryParse<'a>(text) with
        | true, value -> Some value
        | _ -> None

    static member Get<'a, 'b when 'a: (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and 'a :> ValueType and 'a : enum<int64>> (text:string) =

        match Enum.TryParse<'a>(text) with
        | true, value -> Some value
        | _ -> None

let a = AsEnum.Get<BindingFlags>.Get "DeclaredOnly"
```

to try to see if I could get the compiler to infer which overload to call, but if fails with an ambiguity error